# How to selectively use the Google Play Services packages?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, build, dex-limit

I am using the following plugins in my Unity android game:

1) Admob

2) Google Play Games

3) Unity IAP

I was getting an "Unable to convert classes into dex format" error when I tried to build.

> trouble writing output: Too many field references to fit in one dex
>   file: 65681; max is 65536.

I want to reduce the field references, instead of implementing multidex.
Could someone explain how to selectively use the Google Play Services packages?
In my Assets\Plugins\Android\libs folder I have following files:

play-services-ads-15.0.1.aar

play-services-ads-base-15.0.1.aar

play-services-ads-identifier-15.0.1.aar

play-services-ads-lite-15.0.1.aar

play-services-auth-16.0.0.aar

play-services-auth-api-phone-15.0.1.aar

play-services-auth-base-15.1.0.aar

play-services-base-15.0.1.aar

play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar

play-services-drive-15.0.1.aar

play-services-games-15.0.1.aar

play-services-gass-15.0.1.aar

play-services-tasks-15.0.1.aar

I am implementing Ads, Leaderboard, Achievements and IAP in my game.
If there are any .aar packages in the above mentioned list which is not needed for implementing Ads,Leaderboard, Achievements, or IAP , then please let me know, so that I can remove it.

Comment: I have made big changes in the description.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following this guide to make your app a multiplex application which will allow you to bypass that maximum:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already gone through that. I just wanted to know if I have included any package by mistake, which can be removed.

Comment: @Aravind How could we know that, without going through every line of your code?  Additionally you didn't do that correctly, or you wouldn't be getting multidex errors.

Comment: @GabeSechan  I have made a huge change in the question. This is what I was trying to ask. Really sorry for not asking properly in the first place.

Comment: @Aravind You can turn on proguard.  Beyond that, the answer is multidex.  And I'm not sure why you're trying to avoid it-  it was a pain pre-21, but post-21 its almost automatic.